# Can you create \DateTimeZone with custom parameters?

Tags: php, datetime, time, timezone

I am working on some tests for a date/time subsystem and want to have coverage for the different combinations of timezone parameters (offsets, DST, etc).

The constructor for [`\DateTimeZone`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) only accepts one of the standard [timezone names](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

Is is possible to create a `\DateTimeZone` object from a custom set of rules, eg. my own offset and DST definition?

My worry is that if I pick a list of names, my test has an dependency on the timezonedb (which may change in the future), and it is also very tedious to go through the names to find all of the various combinations needed for adequate test coverage.

I have contemplated using [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) to muck with the internals of a `\DateTimeZone` object, but want to avoid that route if there is a better option.

Comment: You need to extend \DateTime and then you can do this

Comment: Like @JohnConde said, just extend `DateTimeZone` class and implement your own logic.